# RDWeb asking for credentials on only one of two servers

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

I am customizing the RDWeb application for Remote Desktop Service for Windows Server 2012.

I have configured two separate servers for RDWeb, and the RDWeb application is generated for both the servers. I access the remote app of second server using the RDWeb application of first server through single UI. The remote apps from both servers are coming into single UI.

Suppose I have two calculator applications from both the servers, let's call them `cal1` and `cal2`. When I click on `cal1`, then the calculator application runs from first server without asking for any credentials. When I click on `cal2` then it ask for credentials, and if I provide the credentials then the calculator application from second server runs.

When I click on `cal2`, it should not ask for credentials. The RDWeb application is auto-generated and uses form authentication. For this, I need to share cookies between both the servers. I have use the same machine key in web config of both the applications, but that is not working.